# SQL aggregation/join over non mutually exclusive variables

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, inner-join, where-clause

what is the most efficient way of doing this query:

I have 5 columns in a table: A (unique identifer), B (grouping variable), C (grouping variable), D (date value), E (numerical value), and F (numerical value) where column D = yesterday.

B and C are not mutually exclusive.  I need to find sum(E) and sum(E, where E > 0) for all C, with no other filter at this time aside from date (column D).  I then need to find, again with no other filter aside from column D, all B where sum (E) = 0.  I need to from this extract all A attached to this last query with B and E.  Then, I need to join those A values with the sum queries on E I did for C.  I'm at a loss on the most efficient way to do this from a computational efficiency standpoint.

Is there a way I could run the first query of all records where D = yesterday and manipulate the data locally from there, as opposed to running several queries with the external database?

Thank you.

Edit:

Table:

```
Column A  Column C  Column B  Column D    Column E  Column F
1         A         A         09/26/2014        50      1000                   
2         A         B         09/26/2014       -20       300
3         A         C         09/26/2014        80     23500         
4         B         A         09/26/2014       -50      5000
5         B         B         09/26/2014        40      3100
6         B         C         09/26/2014        10      4500
1         A         A         09/25/2014        50      1000                   
2         A         B         09/25/2014       -20       300
3         A         C         09/25/2014        80     23500         
4         B         A         09/25/2014       -50      5000
5         B         B         09/25/2014        40      3100
6         B         C         09/25/2014        10      4500
```

My Desired Result Is:

```
Column A  Column C  Column B  Column D    Column E  Column F  Sum(E on C/D)  Sum(E > 0 on C/D)
1         A         A         09/26/2014        50      1000            110                130
4         B         A         09/26/2014       -50      5000              0                 50
```

Comment: Edit your question and add sample data and desired results.  Your description is really, really hard to follow.

Comment: Apologies in advance for doing a poor job on formatting the table.

Comment: Still pretty confusing how did you get 110 in column Sum(E on C/D) for result or 130 for Sum(E > 0 on C/D). Could you check your question again and rectify if anything is to be corrected.

Comment: 110 is the sum of 50, -20, 80 where Column C = A and Column D = 9/26/2014, 130 is the sum of 50, 80 where Column C = A and Column D = 9/26/2014 and E > 0.

Answer (score 0):

Given your specifed table the following query will give you your specified desired result

```
select min(columna) keep
         (dense_rank first
          order by columnb) columna
     , columnc
     , min(columnb) columnb
     , columnd
     , min(columne) keep
         (dense_rank first
          order by columnb) columne
     , min(columnf) keep
         (dense_rank first
          order by columnb) columnf
     , sum(columne) sume_1
     , sum(case
             when columne > 0 then columne
             else 0
           end) sume_2
from mytable
where columnd = to_date('09/26/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
group by columnc
       , columnd
```